# New Page shortcut is missing in right click structure group shortcut menu

Tags: cme, web8.5

After upgrading the CMS to SDL 8.5, I am missing the icon for creating the new page on structure group level. Anybody faced the same issue

[image: missing new page]

Comment: Can you verify that the user has the necessary rights and permissions?

Comment: I am the administrator, but if you right-click on the blank area I can see the option. But it is not there in the structure group right-click quick menu

Comment: Did you clear cookies and browser cache?

Comment: I see the same behavior when using the left-handside navigation panel.  If I click inside the structure group on the right hand side panel, the (new) Page menu option does come up.  Perhaps that can help for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked with SDL, and confirmed that this is been removed in Web 8

Comment: In that case, might I suggest you accept your own answer so this question "becomes closed".